# Firebase Sign-in providers - for Asia

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Firebase. In my ap. I am turning on "Sign-in providers" from the Firebase Control Panel - I see US social networks such as Facebook, Google, Twitter etc. However, I would like to tie into Asian social networks... are there any? (Of most interest, India, China... Russia, Brazil). I cannot find anything on the Firebase admin page. Could somebody point me to a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet may be to use a [Custom Authentication System](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth). But the easiest will be to use one of the 'Sign-in providers'.